# menu bar sticky only in PC

Tags: css

I want to fix my menu bar.

My menu bar is sticky now. Even a mobile device(like iphone, ipad...) I would like to fix my menu bar not sticky in mobile device.

- PC (bigger than ipad) - Sticky menu bar
- Mobile (ipad, iphone, etc) - not sticky menu bar

Please use css.
Thank you, have a nice day!

Comment: share a working fiddle

Comment: Elaborate your problem. unable to understand Your Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Media Query** is your friend if you want to change styles for different devices.

Here are some documents:

- [MDN - CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)
- [W3C - Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

[Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) is a good example to see how to use media query.

- [Bootstrap - Responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) - see how it works
- [Github - bootstrap/less/responsive-utilities.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/responsive-utilities.less) - source

Comment: Thank you Sibevin:) It's helpful to me.